# Assume the distribution is normal. Use the area of the normal curve to answer the question. Round to the nearest whole percent.

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

The average size of the fish in a lake is 11.4 inches, with a standard deviation of 3.2 inches. Find the probability of catching a fish longer than 17 inches.

I posted another question on standard deviation earlier, but I'm unable to find clear results on how to solve this problem specifically either.

I know the equation for standard deviation but the part I cannot find any information online is how to solve "longer than 17 inches". I keep finding similar question that will ask to find the probability in between two numbers but I can't find much else.

Comment: How many standard deviations is $17$ inches away from $11.4$ inches?

Comment: I assume you are getting your answer from a printed normal table. You may have to see various versions of that process before you're confident using it. Consider my Answer one of those versions. There will be others in your textbook and class notes (as you mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

You have $X \sim\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=11.4,\sigma=3.2).$ You seek $P(X > 17) - 1 - P(X \le 17) = 0.0401,$ to four places.

Here is the exact numerical answer from R, where `pnorm` is a normal CDF.[If you're using a statistical calculator you should be able to use it to get the same answer.]

```
1 - pnorm(17, 11.4, 3.2)
[1] 0.04005916
```

Because $17 - 11.4 = 5.6$ and $5.6/3.2 = 1.75$ you're asking for the probability of a fish with length more than 1.75 standard deviations above the mean. By the Empirical Rule the probability in a normal distribution more than $2\sigma$ above the mean is only about 2.5%.
So, if you're familiar with this rule, you should not be surprised that the numerical answer is so small.

If you are supposed to get the answer by standardizing and using a printed CDF table of the standard normal distribution, you could begin as follows:

$$P(X \le 17) = P\left(\frac{X=\mu}{\sigma} 
\le \frac{17 - 11.4}{3.2}\right) = P(Z \le 1.75),$$
where $Z$ has a standard normal distribution.

I will leave it to you to figure out how to get the
answer from a printed table. Various textbooks have
different styles of normal tables, so you will have
to figure out how to use the table in *your* book.
You will start by finding 1.75 in the *margins* of the table and getting a relevant probability from the *body* of the table.

In the figure below, the left-hand panel shows the
problem on a scale of inches and the right-hand panel
shows the 'standardized' version of the problem compatible with printed tables. In both cases the total area under the density curve is $1,$ and the final numerical answer is the area to the right of the dotted vertical line.

[image]

R code to make the figure (in case anyone wants to see it):

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 curve(dnorm(x, 11.4, 3.2), 0, 25, lwd=2, ylab="Density", 
       xlab="Inches", main="NORM(11.4, 3.2)")
  abline(h=0, col="green2")
  abline(v=17, col="red", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
 curve(dnorm(x, 0, 1), -3.5, 3.5, lwd=2, ylab="Density",
       xlab="z", main="NORM(0, 1)")
  abline(h=0, col="green2")
  abline(v=0, col="green2")
  abline(v=1.75, col="red", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Comment: Alright, I got it now. Thanks so much :)